# How to set height of input-tag in HTML depending on the fontsize

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a C#-program which generates inputmasks for a webapplication using HTML and CSS.

On one of these masks i got some input tags like that one:

```
<div class='CellOuter' style='top: 50pt; left: 30pt;'>
    <div class='CellInner TopLeft' style='height: 20pt; width: 45pt; background-color: #eeeeee; '>
        <input id='7219' type="text" name='P150_FELD_RB' style='width: 45pt; border: 0pt;  font-size: 12pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;' maxlength='6' placeholder='-___,_' title='Please use format ###,#' pattern='^[+-]?\d{1,3}([.,]\d{1,1})?$'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

"TopLeft"  in the class attribute means that the content of the input shall be positioned vertically top and horizontally left.

But when the input has the type "text" the content appears vertically centered.

It seems that i have to set the height, but the height must depend on the fontsize - in my example 12 points.

How can i get the height depending on the fontsize in the C#-program which generates the HTML?

Further i uploaded the complete HTML file to a GitHub repository:

https://github.com/patrickpirzer/InputmaskHtml

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you supply the css too? Or, even better, create a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) snippet with only the relevant code (output html + css, no c#). It will much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Mosh Feu : How can i add an HTML-file as appendix?

Comment: @Mosh Feu : I have created a repository at GitHub in which i uploaded the HTML-file for the inputmask. The link is : https://github.com/patrickpirzer/InputmaskHtml

Comment: You don't need to whole html. Just a piece of code that reproduce that issue you are facing with. Something like you did but with the css so we could actually **see** the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself** showing what the problem is. For this, it's not clear why you need to get the height from C#. You may want to do some research into CSS [`em` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems) which are based on the size of the fonts. Also of note: the point unit is mostly used in print media, not screen media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
In the style the height must be set to "auto".
So the height is set automatically.